# Running Total Issue when Narrowing Down

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have query that works fine when it is run with no single restrictions:

```
SELECT  Reportno,
       SUM(SUM(ElapsedTime)) OVER (PARTITION BY NonProductive ORDER BY REPORTNO) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
FROM dbo.DailyOperations o
WHERE NonProductive IN (1) and WellID = 'ZCQ-5' AND JobID = 'Original' 
GROUP BY ReportNo,NonProductive
ORDER BY ReportNo;
```

This will give me:

```
Reportno    RUNNINGTOTAL
9                5
14             10.5
15              14
```

If I run the above query with ReportNo = 14 then I get

```
Reportno        RUNNINGTOTAL
14                  5.5
```

Basically I need the query to show 10.5 (The running Total) when I select a single Reportno. I am not sure where to modify this to get it to work.

Also, I am building this in Visual Studio SSRS and did try to modify the Set expression for: Value as `=RunningValue(Fields!RUNNINGTOTAL.Value,sum, "DownTime")` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery, as in:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (SELECT Reportno,
             SUM(SUM(ElapsedTime)) OVER (PARTITION BY NonProductive ORDER BY REPORTNO) AS RUNNINGTOTAL
      FROM dbo.DailyOperations o
      WHERE NonProductive IN (1) and WellID = 'ZCQ-5' AND JobID = 'Original' 
      GROUP BY ReportNo, NonProductive
     ) r
WHERE r.ReportNo = 14
ORDER BY ReportNo;
```

Comment: it works great. Thank you very much . I suspected I needed to use one but never I have never had to use one before. This will go a long way to helping me get better.

Comment: I ran into an issue that I didn't anticiapte. Basically on days that do no have any NonProducitve it isn't calculating the running total. Is it possible to get the last instanstance of the running total when this is blank. I tried adding Case When but it only shows 0 and doesn't add the preivous total to it.